# jquery DataTables erroring on search box

Tags: pdo, datatables

Trying to get DataTables to work with PDO. I found this script online and it works fine, BUT, when I set ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES to false the search capability does not work and reports back this error.

I cannot view the json response as there is none to view when this error happens, however, in all other cases other than using the search the json is returned properly and it works perfectly fine.  Since the error only happens when emulation is set to false I am thinking this has something to do with binding?  I cannot figure this one out as I don't see anything wrong that is sticking out at me.

Also, I am not looking to turn on emulation as a solution either.  Help would be very appreciated.

**the get in firebug:**

```
http://www.example.com/assets/data-tables/test-pdo.php?sEcho=3&iColumns=4&sColumns=&iDisplayStart=0&iDisplayLength=10&mDataProp_0=0&mDataProp_1=1&mDataProp_2=2&mDataProp_3=3&sSearch=d&bRegex=false&sSearch_0=&bRegex_0=false&bSearchable_0=true&sSearch_1=&bRegex_1=false&bSearchable_1=true&sSearch_2=&bRegex_2=false&bSearchable_2=true&sSearch_3=&bRegex_3=false&bSearchable_3=true&iSortCol_0=2&sSortDir_0=asc&iSortingCols=1&bSortable_0=false&bSortable_1=true&bSortable_2=true&bSortable_3=true&_=1388479579319
```

**Error in firebug:**

```
<br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number' in /home/test/public_html/assets/data-tables/test-pdo.php:107
Stack trace:
#0 /home/test/public_html/assets/data-tables/test-pdo.php(107): PDOStatement-&gt;execute()
#1 /home/test/public_html/assets/data-tables/test-pdo.php(155): TableData-&gt;get('accounts', 'account_id', Array)
#2 {main}
  thrown in <b>/home/test/public_html/assets/data-tables/test-pdo.php</b> on line <b>107</b><br />
```

**db connection:**

```
$db = new PDO("mysql:host=$db_host;dbname=$db_database;charset=utf8", $db_user, $db_pass, array(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false, PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION, PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true));
```

**processing:**

```
<?php

/*
 * Script:    DataTables server-side script for PHP and MySQL
 * Copyright: 2012 - John Becker, Beckersoft, Inc.
 * Copyright: 2010 - Allan Jardine
 * License:   GPL v2 or BSD (3-point)
 */

define('INCLUDE_CHECK',true);

// These files can be included only if INCLUDE_CHECK is defined
require '/home/test/public_html/assets/functions/connect.php';

//inject db connection into class
class TableData {
    /** @var \PDO */
    protected $_db;

    public function __construct(\PDO $_db) {
         $this->_db = $_db;
    }

    public function get($table, $index_column, $columns) {

        // Paging
        $sLimit = "";
        if ( isset( $_GET['iDisplayStart'] ) && $_GET['iDisplayLength'] != '-1' ) {
            $sLimit = "LIMIT ".intval( $_GET['iDisplayStart'] ).", ".intval( $_GET['iDisplayLength'] );
        }

        // Ordering
        $sOrder = "";
        if ( isset( $_GET['iSortCol_0'] ) ) {
            $sOrder = "ORDER BY  ";
            for ( $i=0 ; $i<intval( $_GET['iSortingCols'] ) ; $i++ ) {
                if ( $_GET[ 'bSortable_'.intval($_GET['iSortCol_'.$i]) ] == "true" ) {
                    $sortDir = (strcasecmp($_GET['sSortDir_'.$i], 'ASC') == 0) ? 'ASC' : 'DESC';
                    $sOrder .= "`".$columns[ intval( $_GET['iSortCol_'.$i] ) ]."` ". $sortDir .", ";
                }
            }

            $sOrder = substr_replace( $sOrder, "", -2 );
            if ( $sOrder == "ORDER BY" ) {
                $sOrder = "";
            }
        }

        /* 
        * Filtering
        * NOTE this does not match the built-in DataTables filtering which does it
        * word by word on any field. It's possible to do here, but concerned about efficiency
        * on very large tables, and MySQL's regex functionality is very limited
        */
        //need this change to only show correct responses from db
        //$test = 100;
        //$sWhere = ""; OR $sWhere = "WHERE account_id < ".$test;

        $sWhere = "";
        if ( isset($_GET['sSearch']) && $_GET['sSearch'] != "" ) {

            // changes for correct display from db plus searching       
            if ($sWhere == ""){
                $sWhere = "WHERE (";
            }
            else {
                $sWhere .= " AND (";
            }

            //$sWhere = "WHERE (";
            for ( $i=0 ; $i<count($columns) ; $i++ ) {
                if ( isset($_GET['bSearchable_'.$i]) && $_GET['bSearchable_'.$i] == "true" ) {
                    $sWhere .= "`".$columns[$i]."` LIKE :search OR ";
                }
            }
            $sWhere = substr_replace( $sWhere, "", -3 );
            $sWhere .= ')';
        }

        // Individual column filtering
        for ( $i=0 ; $i<count($columns) ; $i++ ) {
            if ( isset($_GET['bSearchable_'.$i]) && $_GET['bSearchable_'.$i] == "true" && $_GET['sSearch_'.$i] != '' ) {
                if ( $sWhere == "" ) {
                    $sWhere = "WHERE ";
                }
                else {
                    $sWhere .= " AND ";
                }
                $sWhere .= "`".$columns[$i]."` LIKE :search".$i." ";
            }
        }

        // SQL queries get data to display
        $sQuery = "SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS `".str_replace(" , ", " ", implode("`, `", $columns))."` FROM `".$table."` ".$sWhere." ".$sOrder." ".$sLimit;
        $statement = $this->_db->prepare($sQuery);

        // Bind parameters
        if ( isset($_GET['sSearch']) && $_GET['sSearch'] != "" ) {
            $statement->bindValue(':search', '%'.$_GET['sSearch'].'%', PDO::PARAM_STR);
        }
        for ( $i=0 ; $i<count($columns) ; $i++ ) {
            if ( isset($_GET['bSearchable_'.$i]) && $_GET['bSearchable_'.$i] == "true" && $_GET['sSearch_'.$i] != '' ) {
                $statement->bindValue(':search'.$i, '%'.$_GET['sSearch_'.$i].'%', PDO::PARAM_STR);
            }
        }

        $statement->execute();
        $rResult = $statement->fetchAll();

        $iFilteredTotal = current($this->_db->query('SELECT FOUND_ROWS()')->fetch());

        // Get total number of rows in table
        $sQuery = "SELECT COUNT(`".$index_column."`) FROM `".$table."`";
        //$sQuery = "SELECT COUNT(`".$index_column."`) FROM `".$table."` WHERE account_id < 100";
        $iTotal = current($this->_db->query($sQuery)->fetch());

        // Output
        $output = array(
            "sEcho" => intval($_GET['sEcho']),
            "iTotalRecords" => $iTotal,
            "iTotalDisplayRecords" => $iFilteredTotal,
            "aaData" => array()
        );

        // Return array of values
        foreach($rResult as $aRow) {
            $row = array();         
            for ( $i = 0; $i < count($columns); $i++ ) {

                //else if ( $aColumns[$i] != ' ' )
                if ( $columns[$i] != ' ' )
                {
                    /* General output */
                    //if column is empty give it n/a
                    $row[] = ($aRow[ $columns[$i] ]=="") ? 'n/a' : $aRow[ $columns[$i] ];
                }   

            }
            $output['aaData'][] = $row;
        }

        echo json_encode( $output );
    }

}

header('Pragma: no-cache');
header('Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate');

// Create instance of TableData class
$table_data = new TableData($db);

// Get the data
//$table_data->get('table_name', 'index_column', array('column1', 'column2', 'columnN'));
$table_data->get('accounts', 'account_id', array('account_id', 'account_username', 'account_password', 'account_email'));

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I doubt that anyone will be interested, but I finally figured this out.  The script was trying to use the same binding, :search, multiple times in the statement.

Even though it will always be the same actual value the error was being thrown as it was the same binding.  How I did not see this earlier I do not know, but it is obvious to me now.

```
//$sWhere .= "`".$columns[$i]."` LIKE :search OR ";
$sWhere .= "`".$columns[$i]."` LIKE :searchm".$i." OR ";

// Bind parameters
//if ( isset($_GET['sSearch']) && $_GET['sSearch'] != "" ) {
//  $statement->bindValue(':search', '%'.$_GET['sSearch'].'%', PDO::PARAM_STR);
//}
if ( isset($_GET['sSearch']) && $_GET['sSearch'] != "" ) {
    for ( $i=0 ; $i<count($columns) ; $i++ ) {
        $statement->bindValue(':searchm'.$i, '%'.$_GET['sSearch'].'%', PDO::PARAM_STR);
    }
}
```